# Static Routing with Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255 and Blank Gateway?

Tags: networking, subnet, gateway

What static route configuration (as shown by command line "route PRINT"):

1. Network Destination
2. Netmask
3. Gateway
4. Interface
5. Metric

could be used to reach a specified static route (web proxy) in the Intranet, giving that:

1. Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.255
2. Gateway = BLANK

for a computer in a flat LAN.

I tried Netmask 255.255.255.255 and Gateway 0.0.0.0 (on link) but when trying to ping the web proxy destination IP, it says Network Destination Unreachable!

Any thoughts?

Comment: The mask you are using says that every bit of the IP address is network which means there are no hosts.  Try a mask of 0.0.0.0 which means that every bit of the IP address is host.  All of this assumes one network with no router / outside connections.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I do not understand the question, but if you are trying to reach a resource on the same local network segment, then you do not need a route at all.  It should compare the destination address with your subnet mask, determine it is on the local network segment and directly send to that device

Answer (score 0):

you need 0.0.0.0 for the mask as well if it is the default route

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your gateway as network destination

Comment: I'd suggest that in the future that you put this type of information as a comment and not as an answer.